# Livewire View Doesn't Get Refreshed After Form Submit

Tags: laravel-livewire

```blade
<form class="flex gap-2" wire:submit="applyDiscountCode">
    <input required type="text" class="w-full" wire:model="discountCode" placeholder="Kupon kodu">
    <x-web.button type="submit">Uygula</x-web.button>
</form>

@php
    $discounts = $this->getDiscounts();
@endphp

@if (!$discounts->isEmpty())
    <ul wire:transition>
        @foreach ($discounts as $discount)
            <li wire:key="discount-{{ $discount->id }}" class="flex items-center justify-between">
            
                <span>{{ $discount->name }}</span>

                <span title="İndirimi kaldır" 
                      role="button" 
                      class="text-primary" 
                      wire:click="removeDiscount({{ $discount->id }})"
                >
                
                    <x-fas-x class="!w-4 !h-4" />
                    
                </span>
                
            </li>
        @endforeach
    </ul>
@endif
```

I have a Livewire component and the code you see above is a part of its view. When I submit the form, it attaches a model to a model (so pretty much database table row inserting). Thus, I am expecting to see the added row right after the form (I am sure the row gets inserted). But the view doesn't get refreshed. I need to submit it one more time to see the changes. Any idea why? Thanks.

Comment: I suggest you to do the fetch of the records in the class side (*getDiscounts()*) and assign its result to a public property, in your way the fetch is probably executed only once

Comment: @Pippo where exactly in the class side? Like in mount()? mount() is only run once though.

Comment: I did a test and I discovered that also your technique can work, anyway I suggest you to remove the logic from the blade template and put it into the class. For example you can declare a public property $discounts, turn *getDiscounts()* in a protected method and assign its return value to $discounts in the render() method. I notice that your template is not enclosed in a root tag.

Comment: There is a root tag, that code is just a part of the view. But will that fix my problem? Don't think so. My usage must be valid too.